# how to make function have different numbers of arguments

Tags: haskell

```
buyItem :: Hero -> Item -> Hero

buyItem (Mage n Wealth Gold) item1 = (Mage n Wealth item1)

buyItem (Warrior a item)
    | enough (Warrior a c) >= cost item = (Warrior a c++item)
    | otherwise = (Warrior a c)

buyItem (Mage a b c) item
    | enough (Mage a b c) >= cost item = (Mage a b item)
    | otherwise = (Mage a b c)

RPGdefs.hs:136:1: error:
    Equations for ‘buyItem’ have different numbers of arguments
      RPGdefs.hs:136:1-58
      RPGdefs.hs:(137,1)-(139,31)
    |
136 | buyItem (Mage n Wealth Gold) item1 = (Mage n Wealth item1)
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
buyItem (Warrior a item)
```

It should be this:

```
buyItem (Warrior a) item
```

---

When you write `(Warrior a item)`, it means that `item` is part of `Warrior`, but from the rest of your code it looks like `Warrior` should be first parameter and `item` should be second. That's how the other two cases (the ones with `Mage`) are written.

Comment: data Hero = Mage Integer Ability Item
          | Warrior Style [Item]
            deriving (Show)

Comment: Mage and Warrior have different argument, Mage has 4 and Warrior have 3